# Error in combine_vars(): Faceting variables must have at least one value

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my project I'm analyzing videos of behavioural tests (ladder run) of mice. I do the analysis with deeplabcut. This gives me a csv in the end which i want to analyze with a R-Script I've got from a paper (Weber et al.; "Deep learning-based behavioral profiling of rodent stroke recovery"). But as I'm in general really new to this whole coding topic and have just some basic knowledge in python, I'm really lost regarding setting up this code. I managed to install all the needed packages and am now all the time running into the same error. I tried to solve it with ChatGPT but unfortunately, it didn't work.

[This is the github page where you can download the code](https://github.com/rustlab1/DLC-Gait-Analysis)

This is the Error message:

```
Error in `combine_vars()`:
! Faceting variables must have at least one value
Backtrace:
 1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
 2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
 4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
 5. layout$setup(data, plot$data, plot$plot_env)
 6. ggplot2 (local) setup(..., self = self)
 7. self$facet$compute_layout(data, self$facet_params)
 8. ggplot2 (local) compute_layout(..., self = self)
 9. ggplot2::combine_vars(data, params$plot_env, rows, drop = params$drop)
 Show Traceback
Error in combine_vars(data, params$plot_env, rows, drop = params$drop) :
```

Here's the part of the code where the error appears:

```
(4.1) Overview of Typical Mouse Profile. Each frame of a video is normalized to the left hip (left perspecitve), right hip (right perspective), center back (down perspective)
```

```
# normalize to l-hip, r-hip, d-tail-base
df_norm <- long_data_clean2 %>% full_join(filter(long_data_clean, parameter %in% c("r-hip", "d-tail-base", "l-hip")), by = c("full_id", "mouse", "time", "day", "side")) %>%
  select(mouse, full_id, time, side, day, x_corr.x, y_corr.x, likelyhood.x, parameter.x, x_corr.y, y_corr.y, likelyhood.y, parameter.y) %>% 
  mutate(x_corr_norm = x_corr.x- x_corr.y) %>%  # New variable y_corr_norm which gives the normalized x-coordinate to the hip
 filter(full_id %in% c("0days_Mouse_ID1","0days_Mouse_ID3","3days_Mouse_ID5", "3days_Mouse_ID4"))  # example videos



# We build a  helper function to have control over the range otherwise the facette range may be not 100% symmetrical 
df_norm<- data.table(df_norm)
df_norm[side == "right",y_min := 0]
df_norm[side == "right",y_max := 150]
df_norm[side == "left",y_min := 0]
df_norm[side == "left",y_max := 150]
df_norm[side == "down",y_min := 600]
df_norm[side == "down",y_max := 900]

colors <- c("#974863","#65c95a","#b259d5","#9cbe32","#636ada","#4da12e","#ce47af","#52c580","#e73379","#338637","#de52a3","#319a6b","#d32f50","#58c8a9","#8b44a3","#b3b23d","#c487e0","#729131","#ab3474","#99bb6e","#5861a7","#d1a63b","#8096e0","#e16926","#3dc2cc","#b53624","#50a2d1","#ea6342","#38907c","#e1625f","#226a4d","#de628a","#327243","#e08dbe","#546e19","#975e9e","#e18e31","#99527c","#6faa75","#a4464e","#486a2d","#dc827f","#6d8b4c","#b66024","#bab06d","#9c5831","#90812a","#dd9c6c","#666123","#916d31")


# Here we plot all coordinates of each parameter by normalizing to the hip-x (Left,right) and d-center back-value
PLOT_overview_steps <- ggplot(df_norm, aes(x=x_corr_norm, y=y_corr.x))+
  geom_jitter(aes(fill = factor(parameter.x)), colour = "black", width = 0.10, shape=21, size =1, alpha = 0.4)+ #parameter.x or mouse
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(NA, NA)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=colors) +
  facet_grid(side~full_id, scales = "free")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-120, 350))+
  geom_blank(aes(y = y_min)) +
 geom_blank(aes(y = y_max))+
  theme_bw()
PLOT_overview_steps
```

As I said I tried a lot with ChatGPT as I'm absolutely not into R and also just starting to get into this coding topic with python. So i just tried to solve it with ChatGPT but of course it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share the corresponding part of your code where the error appears? Or are you calling a function from a certain library?
However, from the error message, the error seems to occur during plotting. The visualization package `ggplot2` is trying to facet your plot but the variable for facetting seems te be empty in your data. I hope this helps a bit. Otherwise, without further information, I'm not sure if I can help you

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I edited the text and added the part of the code where the error appears. It appears at the PLOT_overview_steps

Comment: Thanks. It seems your issue is somewhere in the variables that are used for faceting your plot, i.e., in `side` and/or `full_id`. Can you check that these variables have valid entries? You can use e.g., `unique(df_norm$side)` or `sum(is.na(df_norm$side))`

Comment: ok so when I use the sum(is.na(df_norm$side)) the code prints [1] 0 and when I use unique(df_norm$side) the code prints character(0). Does this mean that there is actually one value missing? If so what could I do to fix this? Sorry Im really not understanding everything Im doing so please dont blame me for my ignorance ; )

Comment: When you just type `df_norm$side` and `df_norm$full_id` in the console it should print out the contents of these columns. If the console answers `NULL`, these columns do not exist and something is wrong upstream of your ggplot code. If you get a series of values then probably something is wrong with the plotting code, but by eye it seems allright.

Comment: As @teunbrand says, you might need to check the affected columns in your data and see if they have the values that you would expect. If `unique(df_norm$side)`prints `character(0)` then maybe this column needs to be checked again (how and where is it created and what exactly are its contents)

Comment: I found the problem but dont know how to solve it. The problem is that after filtering the data in the code there is just data for "down" but no data for "left" and "right". Unfortunately Im so bad in reading csv files that I dont know how I should filter the data so the code uses it/if the data is somehow wrong so the code cant use it. Do you have any suggestions on how i could solve it?
LG